# Flutter Custom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

i have a problem with a custom navigation bar.
I can´t change the page in the body. I put 4 diferent texts for tests.
Later i want to have somo widgets with the diffrent pages.
The _buildItem is in a diferent widget but in the same page.

```
class InicioPage extends StatefulWidget {
final int selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return InicioPageState(selectedIndex);
  }
}

class InicioPageState extends State<InicioPage> {
  int selectedIndex;
  InicioPageState(this.selectedIndex);

  final pages = [Text('page 0'),Text('page 1'),   ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        title: Text('Title of App'),     ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(selectedIndex),
      body: pages[selectedIndex],      );     }    }
```

Here is the Navigation Bar. I cut some parts that are not important because the characters.

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  BottomNavBar(this.selectedIndex);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return BottomNavBarState(selectedIndex);
  },}

class BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int selectedIndex;
   BottomNavBarState(this.selectedIndex);
    List<NavigationItem> items = [
    NavigationItem(Icon(Icons.home), Text('Home')),
    NavigationItem(Icon(Icons.location_city), Text('Props')),
      ];
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    child: Row(
    children: items.map((item) { var itemIndex = items.indexOf(item);
    return GestureDetector(  onTap: () {   setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = itemIndex;
                });           },
              child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == itemIndex),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass params in your BottomNavBarState via constructor, just use instead

```
widget.selectedIndex
```